# Unable to draw Bar Graph with already calculated error

Tags: excel, charts, powerbi, bar-chart

I have dataset that looks like this:
[image]

```
TS Days             0           7          14          21          28
Shreds  T0  4.46±0.03   4.42±0.03   4.38±0.02   4.35±0.01   4.31±0.01
        T1  4.41±0.0    4.38±0.03   4.34±0.03   4.31±0.02   4.28±0.02
        T2  4.36±0.03   4.33±0.02   4.29±0.02   4.25±0.01   4.22±0.01
        T3  4.31±0.02   4.29±0.01   4.26±0.02   4.22±0.02   4.18±0.01


Puree   T4  4.40±0.03   4.36±0.03   4.32±0.02   4.29±0.01   4.27±0.01
        T5  4.34±0.04   4.31±0.03   4.28±0.03   4.26±0.02   4.23±0.02
        T6  4.29±0.03   4.26±0.03   4.23±0.02   4.21±0.02   4.19±0.01
Mean        4.37        4.33        4.30        4.27        4.24
```

And I want a graph that looks like this:
[image]

I have tried a lot of stuff but it doesnt work at all. I want to generate this is excel, powerBI or any other tool whatsoever.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just done 1 small series as I won't be typing all your values. If you posted a table of data that people can copy & paste, it all comes in one cell.

[image]

Create a column chart using the data X & Y.

The select the data series in the chart and add chart element, choose "error bars" in the list. Then more error bar options, custom and link to the cells with the error value for both positive and negative values.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. But  want a clustered bar chart. Just like above plot the entries used are for 0. But as in the data, I want to draw for 0, 7, 14, 21 and 28. The bars for 0,7,14,21,28 should be together for each of T0, T1...T6

Comment: They will be - you just have to sort your data properly, as I had to type it in I was not doing more than 1 set.