# Placing error bars into the foreground of barplots (excel)

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I'm trying to have the error bars associated with the data in the background in the foreground of both data sets in this barplot.[image: f]

The error bars become hidden behind the foreground data. I've tried to move around the chart series but haven't really been successful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904918/4961700

Comment: I've done this but the error bars still disappear behind the foreground data. It's a layered plot and the error is only associated with the grey bar.